# adding to SetValue Methode Php Variable In PhpWord

Tags: php, docx, phpword

i am using the PhpWord To convert a page to docx file

in my main page i have a form

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#save', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var textareaValue = $('#content').summernote('code');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'convert_doc.php',
            data: ({text:textareaValue}),
            success: (
                function (data) {
                    $(".result").html(data)
                }

            )
        });

    });
```

```html
<form method="post" novalidate="novalidate" id="save" >
  <textarea class="summernote input-block-level" id="content" name="content" rows="18"></textarea>                                                               <buttontype="submit" >save file</button>
 </form>
```

and in my convert_doc.php file i have this code:

```html
if(isset($_POST['text'])){


require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    $desc1 = $_POST['text'];

    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('tamplate.docx');

    $templateProcessor->setValue('summer', 'Word Document processing');

    $templateProcessor->saveAs('export.docx');

}
```

when I am trying to replace the Word Document processing to

```
$templateProcessor->setValue('summer', $desc1);
```

my saved file is corrupted.
I understand the second value has to be plain text. how can I put the PHP variable instead of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `$_POST['text']` contains invalid data (in terms of MS Word) posted by JS. First debug and try fixing it.